# C function in view controller issue

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, c, uiviewcontroller

I use this function in my UIViewController

```
void showMap()
{

}
```

if I use objective-c function, I can call `self.view`, but how to call this in C-function inside UIViewContoller?

(I need to use `self.view = myObject` inside C function, and when I try to use `self.view = myObject` xcode says that there is no variable `self`)

**Update:**

I need this to use in Unity 3d

Comment: @PaulGalavic And what prohibits you from using it?

Comment: xcode doesn't see this variable self

Comment: Why not turn the c function into an objective-c function? It can't be hard, and you'll have instant access to self.

Comment: I need it for using in Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    In . m file 

    for example  In LoginPage.m


    #import "LoginPage.h"

    LoginPage *loginP;

    @interface LoginPage ()

    @end

    @implementation LoginPage


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.title=@"Login";
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        loginP = self;  //assign self to loginP 
    }

    void showMap()
    {

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 50, 100)];
        [loginP.view addSubview:view];  


//Now you can use self inside c function ..and access any method of class 

    }
```

Comment: no, I need view of current view controller

Comment: I didn't understand , what u want ,,describe in detail ..

Comment: loginP.view is view of current view controller ,,,it will do your work just try it ,,

Answer (score 0):

I fount the solution

```
void showMap(UIViewController *self)
{
    self.view = newView;
}
```

Comment: If this is the right solution then why are you accepting the other Answer.